# only first row getting insert when using form collection in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I tried to fetch the form collection values and insert into DB. But the typical issue which I am facing is the first row only getting inserted in DB. My code as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection Students)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string[] names = Students["name"].Split(char.Parse(","));
            string[] dnos = Students["dno"].Split(char.Parse(","));
            string[] adds = Students["address"].Split(char.Parse(","));

            student stds = new student();

            for (var i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                stds.name = names[i];
                stds.dno = dnos[i];
                stds.address = adds[i];
                stds.active = true;
                db.students.AddObject(stds);

            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(Students);
    }
```

Please help with this.

Answer (score 3):

move save changes in loop and `student stds` also

```
            for (var i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                student stds = new student();
                stds.name = names[i];
                stds.dno = dnos[i];
                stds.address = adds[i];
                stds.active = true;
                db.students.AddObject(stds);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `student stds = new student();` into for loop. It's id not refreshed, i think.

Comment: I just moved the student initialization inside the loop. It is working friend. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From you post it is rather difficult to figure out what is the DB you use, but very often error in such case - your don't control primary key. So you add students (`stds`) in the loop but it is initialized with some unpredictable (at least with NULL), but second try will discover that such record already exists.

Answer (score 0):

student class defined here seems to be a reference object, so every time you modified it in the for loop, it always modified the single object instance created ahead. You need to have new object in each loop turn like:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            student stds = new student();    
            stds.name = names[i];
            stds.dno = dnos[i];
            stds.address = adds[i];
            stds.active = true;
            db.students.AddObject(stds);

        }
```